# Redirect to different Action View with jQuery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

Just a quick question.
I have got a page with cascade ComboBoxes...
So if the user select any item from first Combobox, then website getting second combobox items from server request...

The issue us if something goes wrong when I am getting this second data, I mean if there is an error, I want the website to redirect to ErrorView rather than ComboBox View.

**JQUERY**

```
   $("#SelectedProductTypeID").change(function () {
        var pType = $("#SelectedProductTypeID").val();

        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "User/GetProductNameList";
        var ddlsource = "#SelectedProductTypeID";

        $.getJSON(url, { pTypeId: pType }, function (data) {

            if (typeof (data.errorMessage) != undefined) {
                alert(data.errorMessage);
            }

            var items = '';
            $("#SelectedProductNameID").empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, row) {
                items += "<option value='" + row.value + "'>" + row.text + "</option >";
            });
            $("#SelectedProductNameID").html(items);
        });
    });
```

**CONTROLLER ACTION**

```
    public JsonResult GetProductNameList(int pTypeId)
    {
        var (list, error) = productRepository.GetProductList(configuration);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            return Json(new { ErrorMessage = "Fail to get product name list" });
        }
       .....
       ......
        return Json(ProductNameList);
    }
```

Instead of showing an Alert, I would like to redirect to Erro View in the Shared folder.

I tried this instead of alert

```
                var errorUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "User/ErrorPage";
                $.ajax({
                    url: errorUrl, success: function (data) {

                    }
                });
```

with new Action for error, but didn't work. Still, I am going to the same View. The error view doesn't show.

```
    public IActionResult ErrorPage(string errorText)
    {
        return View("Error", 
            new ErrorViewModel
            {
                ActionName = " ",
                ControllerName = "UserController - ",
                ErrorMessage = errorText
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JQuery you can use window.location

try below short and simple code

```
 var errorUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "User/ErrorPage";
            $.ajax({
                url: errorUrl, success: function (data) {

                }
            });
```

replace this with below code

```
return window.location = '/User/ErrorPage';
```

Comment: Thank you... It works now.. But do you know what was wrong with my code?

Comment: I am also not that much experience person in .net but i think your  var errorUrl is not proper you can set debug and see what was the url in errorUrl.

Comment: And if url is Correct then you have to replace IActionResult with JsonResult because you have call ajax.